# jwt is not defined even after i imported it with require()

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have follow problem:

In my controller `createPost` i need to use the library JWT but it seems to be undefined and i dont know why

```
   const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
   const atob = require("atob");
   import Post from "../models/post";
   export default async function(req, res) {
     const token = req.body.token;
     if (!token) {
       return res.status(403).send({
         message: "Token ungültig, bitte melde dich ab und wieder an."
       });
     }
     jwt.verify(req.body.token, "key", function(err) {
       if (err) {
         res.status(403).send(false);
         return null;
       }
     });
```

as you can see i have importet it up here with `const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");` but its still undefined at line 11.

```
jwt.verify(req.body.token, "myKey", function(err) {
```

What i am doing wrong here?

Here is also my error message:

> ERROR  jwt is not defined
>   19:50:35
>
> at default (api\controllers\createPost.js:11:3)   at Layer.handle
>   [as handle_request] (node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>   at next (node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)   at
>   Route.dispatch (node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)   at
>   Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)   at
>   node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22   at
>   Function.process_params
>   (node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)   at next
>   (node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)   at Function.handle
>   (node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)   at router
>   (node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)   at Layer.handle [as
>   handle_request] (node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)   at
>   trim_prefix (node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)   at
>   node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7   at
>   Function.process_params
>   (node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)   at next
>   (node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)   at
>   node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5   at invokeCallback
>   (node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)   at done
>   (node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)   at IncomingMessage.onEnd
>   (node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)   at IncomingMessage.emit
>   (events.js:203:15)   at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit
>   (domain.js:448:20)   at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)

Comment: The only way two ways I can see that happening are both unlikely. 1. If `jsonwebtoken` exports the value `undefined`, which the one on `npm` does not. 2. If you have a [cyclic relationship](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles) between `jsonwebtoken` and the module you're trying to use it in (which seems unlikely). Or maybe if there's a cycle between the module you're using it in and the module that's using that module?

Comment: **If** it were #2, you could solve it by using the ESM module loader instead of the default CJS one. With ESM, instead of `jwt` being a constant in your module, it would be a live binding, which means even in a cycle, provided you don't try to *use* it until all the modules are loaded (which I'm guessing you don't, as you have it in an `async` function you're exporting), all is well.

Comment: i got the jwt from `npm i jsonwebtoken`

Comment: I figured. :-) .

Comment: is this error in the same file that you're showing us? maybe you have another file that's using `jwt.something` but jwt is not imported there. You may have copy/pasted this code into another file and forgot to import jwt or you forgot this code has a reference to jwt

Comment: i removed the `async` from the `export default async function` and the error dissapeared.. at the moment i dont need async await but why does it not work with async?

Answer (score 3):

Run the command

```
npm install jsonwebtoken
```

Comment: Please add some more information, whart does this command do and how will it help the OP? It looks like you're installing something however you have not liked any documentation or code that shows how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

createPost.js:11:3

check this file createPost
in that file go to line no 11 you have used jwt but u forgot to declare it.
so declare it using

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
```

also install package

```
npm i jsonwebtoken
```

Comment: Have you checked the question? OP posted `createPost.js` and on line 11 they use `jwt.verify(req.body.token, "key", function(err) {` but on line 1 they declared `const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");`.

Answer (score -3):

Did you try with `var`?

```
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
```